# Returning multiple parameters

Tags: c#, class, parameters

I'm trying to return multiple parameters, if that's how to word it. I'm trying to "translate" Python code into C#.

I'm actually not quite sure what exact term I'm searching for, but I know how to do it in Python so I'll just show my code.

```
class Staff
{
    public String name;
    public int age;

    /* Now in Python, you can easily write this following, but I have no
       idea how this works in C#. I basically want to return all the values
       for each employee in the "Staff" class */

    def desc(self):
        desc_str = "%s is %s years old." % (self.name, self.age)
        return desc_str

}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Staff Jack = new Staff();
        Jack.name = "Jack";
        Jack.age = 40;

        Staff Jill = new Staff();
        Jill.name = "Jill";
        Jill.age = 50;

        Console.WriteLine(Jack.desc());
        Console.WriteLine(Jill.desc());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I figured out that what I was searching for was **get, set and ToString()** and will look into it now.
The code I've translated looks like the following now:

```
class Staff
{
    private string name;
    private int age;
    private string yearsold = " years old.";

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return age;
        }
        set
        {
            age = value;
        }
    }

    public string YearsOld
    {
        get
        {
            return yearsold;
        }
        set
        {
            yearsold = value;
        }
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Employee " + Name + " is " + Age + YearsOld;
    }
}

class TestPerson
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Create a new Person object:
        Staff person = new Staff();

        person.Name = "Jack";
        person.Age = 40;
        Console.WriteLine(person);

        person.Name = "Jill";
        person.Age = 50;
        Console.WriteLine(person);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, fix the identation in the python function.

Comment: @Ender Look: There's no Python code in the question.

Comment: @martineau, ohh, I saw fastly the code and I thought thet the part wich started with `def` was a python code, I'm sorry. Also, I am still thinking it is... at least that three lines.

Comment: Yes, those three lines of code are what I would like to "translate" from Python into C#.

Comment: Have you looked at Tuple?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've looked into it, but it's not quite what I'm searching for. I'm trying to make a return function that returns the sentence in the "desc" function filled with all variables for each Staff member (I intend to add more than just name and age but simplified it in order to focus on what exactly I'm searching for)

Comment: The simplest way to get this compile is by adding `public string desc() => $"{name} is {age} years old.";` to Staff. This syntax for creating a string is called string interpolation in case you want to look it up.

Comment: Unfortunately, string interpolation is not quite it either, since those only refer to one specific string. What I'm searching for is something that does "Staff1.name is Staff1.age years old. Staff2.name is Staff2.age years old" etc. However, writing that with 200 Staff members would be a pain, so I'd like a code that refers to all "name" and all "age" of all members in the "Staff" class. Sorry for my poor wording.

Comment: @RayaLaRosse - You can use a collection Ex List, DataTable, Dictionary, Array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a class, you can override the [`ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) function and use the [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) function like so:

```
class Staff
{
    public string name;
    public int age;

    public Staff(string _name, int _age)
    {
        this.name = _name;
        this.age = _age;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} is {1} years old.", this.name, this.age);
    }
}
```

Then to print:

```
Staff Jack = new Staff("Jack", 40);
Console.WriteLine(Jack); // implicitly calls Jack.ToString()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is way shorter than what I wrote and looks so much easier to read. Thank you much!